# Is it possible to add editable-form attribute to a editable form with anjularjs+angular-xeditable?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf, angular-xeditable

Thymyleaf does not allow to add "editable-form" attribute since it is not well formed. Is there any alternative way to do this?

**application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

**Thymyleaf Template**

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="afterSave()" oncancel="cancel()">
</form>
```

- [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html)
- [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/)
- [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/)

Answer (score 0):

AnagularJS directives can be prepended with `data` attributes.

```
<form data-editable-form="" name="tableform" onaftersave="afterSave()" oncancel="cancel()">
</form>
```

Comment: With data-editable-form, angular-xeditable does not recognize form as xeditable attribute

Answer (score 0):

`editable-form="editable-form"` should work as well -- as long as angularjs understands it.  The requirement is that all attributes have values.